# Format a particular cell based on another cell in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I have the following table where I display two row measures; ITD Funds Received and ITD Actual Cost:

[image: Current Table]

The values for these two columns are repeated for each row. What I would like to do is only display the ITD Funds Received in the Funds Received cells and blank value to display in the Actual Cost cell; vice versa for ITD Actual Cost. I would like to end up with a table that looks something like this:

[image: Final Table]

I looked at conditional formatting to no avail. I am not sure how I can reference a row measure label in an OBIEE formula. I was hoping to do something like (pseudo code) this:

```
If row.measure.label = 'Funds Received" then
  funds.received.value
else
  blank
end

If row.measure.label = 'Actual Cost" then
  actual.cost.value
else
  blank
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If figured it out. I made the changes to the pivot table properties. I removed my YTD/ITD measure from the row section. I applied summation before the column measure, and created an appropriate label for the new column created. Here is the end result:

[image: Solution]